# Can we use xquery in eclipse?

Tags: xquery

I want to sort element of an xml file and then some query has to perform over that.For that I want to use xquery. I have gone through various sites but didn't find the accurate solution regarding "how can I write xquery in eclipse.Even I don't know Is it possible to use XQuery in Eclipse? If yes plz help.

Comment: The are commercial solutions like https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/eclipse_plugin.html.

Comment: Why do you want to use Eclipse? If you want to do this only once there are tools like BaseX or eXide which will do the job just fine